# Unable to login to Azure Portal

Tags: azureportal

I'm unable to login to my own subscription. When I try to login the page shows next error: "Your account has been locked. Contact your support person to unlock it, then try again.". The URL of this page looks like [https://login.microsoftonline.com/[ANOTHERORG].onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/...](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%5BANOTHERORG%5D.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/...), but I do not work in ANOTHERORG anymore and I want to login into my own subscription.

The ID of my own subscription should be f77b7b54-c38f-44e0-a471-95a4914cf742. I tried to login multiple times from incognito windows of different browsers and for some reason it tries to login into ANOTHERORG instead of my own. BTW, I used the same email address to login into ANOTHERORG and my own so I do not understand what the problem is, I think Azure should suggest to select which subscription I want to login to. How can the problem could be solved? How can I login into f77b7b54-c38f-44e0-a471-95a4914cf742 ?

Also I'm unable to create issue using https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/create-ticket/ because of the same problem: it tries to login to ANOTHERORG which I do not have access anymore

I hope people from Microsoft are read questions on stackoverflow and will help to solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to find solution: I opened link https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Billing/SubscriptionsBlade which was mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/troubleshoot-sign-in-issue. From here I was able to change my default directory (Switch Directory -> Set your default directory dropdown). Now when I open portal.azure.com it opens my own subscription without an issue.